# Where to obtain Broadcom DW1530 wireless-n wlan half-mini driver?

Tags: fedora, drivers, wifi

I am running Fedora 15 x86_64 on Dell Latitude E5420 which is using Broadcom DW1530 wlan card, have been looking around the web but couldn't find a driver, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Ubuntu page](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201011-6891), that model comes with Ubuntu pre-installed and using the BCM4313 card which uses the broadcom-wl driver which you can download from here: http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

Given the variabilities of componentry installed in machines, you might want to establish the PCI-ID of the card to make sure that you are looking for the correct driver: `$ lspci -vnn | grep 14e4` should return the ID you need to correctly identify the driver(s) that works with your card.

[This page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0Xzyb8qflfYJ:www.wikidevi.com/wiki/Dell_Wireless_1530_Wireless-N_WLAN_Mini-Card+dw+1530+broadcom&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&ie=UTF-8)  (only available in cache) suggests that the driver is BCM43228, which means that you would still be able to use broadcom-wl.

Comment: thanks a lot, follow the README on http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php and it works now